# JSF 2.0 custom composite controls & nesting

Tags: jsf, composite-component

Greetings,
I'm trying to implement my custom TAB control.
I'd like it to be based on new composite components feature of JSF 2.0:

```
<i:tabControl width="480" height="320" value="#{backingBean.someIterable}" var="tab" >
    <i:tabItem href="#{tab.href}" caption="#{tab.caption}"/>
<i:tabControl/>
```

The problem is I don't know how to implement repeater for Composite component.
How to get access to nested element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can really iterate over the child components. Check
`<composite:insertChildren/>`, `<composite:renderFacet .../>` and `<composite:insertFacet .../>` tags for child/facet processing.

Comment: it looks like they only allow to copy the nested elements from page where composite control is placed into composite:implementation portion.